# SELECT query repeating rows unintentionally

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am learning SQL and have been working on this query:

```
SELECT 
    [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] 
FROM 
    [Theme] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [ThemeType] ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType]
JOIN 
    [ProductTheme] ON [ProductTheme].[ThemeId]=[Theme].[PK_Theme]
WHERE 
    ProductTheme.ProductID LIKE '%' 
    AND ProductTheme.ThemeId = Theme.PK_Theme 
    AND COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], 'null') LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN [THEMETYPE].[TYPE] IS NULL 
         THEN 0 
         ELSE 1 
    END, 
    [THEMETYPE].[TYPE]
```

There are two parts that need to be variable. Both are the LIKE statements.

The second one works perfect I can change it to %, Null or %[0-9]% to get all, only nulls or only non nulls

The first one works fine when it is specifically assigned:

```
WHERE ProductTheme.ProductID = 1
```

[image]

However I need this also to be variable, allowing for a specific number or all numbers, when I do this:

```
WHERE ProductTheme.ProductID LIKE '%'
```

I am getting repeats:
[image]

How do I fix this?

EDIT: Sample Data For Tables:

Theme Table:

[image]

Product Table:

[image]

ProductTheme Table:

[image]

Comment: Please show the sample data for the tables.

Comment: More to the point, please explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Want your filter by [X-Y]? for example get the rows with `ProductID IN [x-y]`, `[x,y]` is an interval.

Comment: Avoid JOIN+DISTINCT combo, use IN/EXISTS: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2013/07/debunking-the-myth-that-join-is-faster-than-in.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest fix that comes to my mind would be inserting a `DISTINCT` clause right after the SELECT like

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Theme].[Name], [ThemeType].[Type] 
FROM [Theme] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN [ThemeType] 
ON [Theme].[ThemeTypeId] = [ThemeType].[PK_ThemeType]
JOIN [ProductTheme]
ON [ProductTheme].[ThemeId]=[Theme].[PK_Theme]
WHERE ProductTheme.ProductID LIKE '%' AND ProductTheme.ThemeId = Theme.PK_Theme AND COALESCE([THEME].[THEMETYPEID], 'null') LIKE '%[0-9]%' 
ORDER  BY CASE WHEN [THEMETYPE].[TYPE] IS NULL 
THEN 0 
ELSE 1 
END, 
[THEMETYPE].[TYPE]
```

I haven't test it, but judging from your output it should work.

Comment: THis works but there is a case where I get this error: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified. Is there an if clause I could use to prevent it?

Comment: Well, obviously, the easiest way to overcome this problem would be to include the column to be sorted by (i.e. CASE WHEN [THEMETYPE].[TYPE] IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS srt) into the output list, IF your are able to ignore it later-on in your output processing ...